# LinkedBlockingQueue iOS Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to achieve something in Swift that has been achieved on Android using **LinkedBlockingQueue**.

The app I am working on connects to a device using a WebSocket connection using the Starscream library.

The app can send a message to the device requesting a chunk of Data. This message can only be send once if no response back has been received. All the chunks of data will used at the end for creating a file.

The data Sent/Received from the app and the device is serialised data from a Proto file.

The problem I am facing is that I don't know how to handle this in a function that need to request a certain amount of chunks of data since the response from the device happens outside my function.

```
func getFile(at index:Int, outputFormat:RecordQuality){

    let aFile= fileArray[index]

    var bytesRemaining = aFle.lengthBytes
    var offset:Int64 = 0

    while bytesRemaining > 0{

        //This function deals with the webSocket write action and deals with all the proto Classes
        readFileReq(fileName: aTrack.name, offset: ofset, length: AppSocketManager.dataReqSize)

        isWaitingForData = true
        print("\(logClassName) TEST -> Blocking!")
        while isWaitingForData{

        }

        print("\(logClassName) TEST -> End Blocking!")

        offset += Int64(2352 * 8)
        bytesRemaining -= offset
        print("\(logClassName) TEST -> \(offset)")

    }

    print("\(logClassName) get file finished")

}
```

aFile is a variable type ReqFile

```
private struct ReqFile{
    var name:String
    var lengthBytes:Int64
    var startAddress:UInt32
    var isAudio:Bool
    var numberBlock:UInt32

    init(name:String, lengthBytes:Int64) {
        self.name = name
        self.lengthBytes = lengthBytes
        self.startAddress = 0
        self.isAudio = false
        self.numberBlock = 0
    }

}
```

On the other side the webSocket delegate method for data received is

```
func websocketDidReceiveData(socket: WebSocketClient, data: Data) {
    /* Deal with data */
    isWaitingForData = false 
}
```

This Code will never reach websocketDidReceiveData because I am basically blocking the while that expects isWaitingData to be false to exit, am I?

Any Ideas?

Comment: Maybe it is better to learn aboud GCD (Grand Central Dispatch) rather than inventing your own solution.

Comment: Thank you. Before posting the question I had a look at this link https://www.swiftbysundell.com/posts/a-deep-dive-into-grand-central-dispatch-in-swift Which one do you think would solve my issue?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Is the solution accurate or is there something you think it is not true. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I decided to subclass Operation:

```
import UIKit

class TrackOperation:Operation{

    //MARK: Vars
    private var _executing  = true
    private var _finished  = false

    override var isAsynchronous: Bool{return true}
    override var isConcurrent: Bool{return true}

    override var isExecuting: Bool{
        get{
            return _executing
        }
        set{
            willChangeValue(for: \.isExecuting)
            _executing = newValue
            didChangeValue(for: \.isExecuting)
        }
    }
    override var isFinished: Bool{
        get{
            return _finished
        }
        set{
            willChangeValue(for: \.isFinished)
            _finished = newValue
            didChangeValue(for: \.isFinished)
        }

    }

    private (set) var fileName:String
    private (set) var bytesRemaining:Int64

    var offset:Int64{
        return Int64(data.count)
    }
    private (set) var data:Data = Data()
    var incomingData:Data? {
        didSet{
            updateData()
        }
    }

    /*** Completion Blocks ***/
    var onMore:(()->())?



    //MARK:- Constructor
    init(fileName:String, bytesRemaining:Int64) {

        self.fileName = fileName
        self.bytesRemaining = bytesRemaining

        super.init()

        qualityOfService = .background
        queuePriority = .normal

    }



    //MARK:- Lifecycle methods
    override func start() {

        print("\(logClassName) Start ripping process \(bytesRemaining)")

        isExecuting = true
        isFinished = false

        onMore?()

    }


    //MARK:- Private methods
    private func updateData(){
        guard let incomingData = incomingData else { return }

        data += incomingData
        print("\(logClassName) Total \(offset) of \(bytesRemaining)")

        if bytesRemaining > offset{
            onMore?()
        }
        else{
            print("\(logClassName) Finished RIPPING")
            isExecuting = false
            isFinished = true
        }

    }



    //MARK:- Public methods




}
```

The code runs on the background and ask for more data using onMore block once the requested has been provided. So It can be declared like that:

```
func ripTrack(at index:Int, outputFormat:RecordQuality){

    let aTrack = cdTrackArray[0]

    trackOperation = TrackOperation(fileName: aTrack.name, bytesRemaining: aTrack.lengthBytes)

    trackOperation?.onMore = {
        print("\(self.logClassName) GIVE More Cookies!")

        self.dealWithOperation()

    }

    trackOperation?.completionBlock = {
        print("\(self.logClassName) COMPLETION BLOCK FOR Track Operation")
    }

    currentState = .ripping
    self.trackOperation?.start()

}


func websocketDidReceiveData(socket: WebSocketClient, data: Data) {

    trackOperation?.incomingData = data 

}
```

F.Y.I The file I mentioned in my question was a audio track in chunks of data as I gets ripped.